# python:I want to read the csv file which contains chinese,I used the 'reload(sys)' but it can't work

Tags: python

I use Python 3.5 and PyCharm.

My code:

```
import importlib,sys
importlib.reload (sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

The error:

```
  sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") is strictly discouraged.

In Python 3, the default encoding has been switched from ascii to utf-8. First check what encoding is set from python prompt using the following commands.

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

You can explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8 using the following ways:

**Option 1: Add encoding line in top of file name**

Add the below line after *.py file.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

**Option 2 : Through PYTHONIOENCODING export variable**

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
$ python test.py
```

**Option 3 : Using encode function**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = u'オリンピック'
print text.encode("utf-8")
print text
```

Comment: Thanks!!!after improved：import pandas as pd
import sys
sys.stdout.encoding
a = pd.read_csv('student.csv', 'r', 'utf-8')
print (a[:5])。。。。。It worked,but there was a warning:ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  Was I used the worng way to read this file?